# Django with AWS, help me find my target wsgi script

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wsgi

Okay, so I recently had my whole website up and running. However, I switched computers and to retrieve the websites code I downloaded the ZIP of the project. Whenever I run eb deploy errors arise as it says my WSGI points to a file that doesn't exist. Here is my project structure.

```
-suliman_baldo

    -bin

    -include
    -lib
    -suliman_baldo
        -.ebextension
        -01-flask.config
        -django.config
    -.elasticbeanstalk
        -config.yml
    -gallery
    -main
    -static
    -templates
    -suliman_baldo
       -admin.py
       -settings.py
       -urls.py
       -wsgi.py
```

Here is my django.config file

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: suliman_baldo/wsgi.py
```

This is weird as the project structure is the same as before but the WSGI Path has changed

Comment: do you have wsgi.py in suliman_baldo/suliman_baldo folder?

Comment: yeah I have one. i just solved the error by using eb config command and writing it in there. weird stuff . thank you !

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution. my WSGI path was right but for some reason wasn't working. So I wrote eb config into terminal where you can change the WSGI path there.

Comment: consider writing more details about eb config. Probably it will be helpful for other developers!